# What options do I have when my team leader is not assigning me any tasks?

Tags: work-environment, team

I am totally frustrated with my team leader because of his attitude. It's not only me, but the entire team is fed up with his nature.

He is **not assigning tasks to me** for the last 2.5 months and if I discussed this matter with senior management then **he would cause me more trouble**, which I experienced before.

This being **my first job**, it's **not acceptable** to me that I am not learning anything as he is not giving me any tasks.

What are my options, dealing with him and this situation in general?

he comes late to office which is not my concern but problem is that he want every one to seat late daily to do work .he created lot of dependencies on him so we keep on waiting for his response as whole day he is busy  in meetings.
he is not giving me work from which i can learn he just wasting my time.our company strength is 30 + few out source emp.

i think my problem got personal with him as i have complained about him twice so he is angry with me,it was necessary to complain at that situation because things were above my head now he is taking revenge of it.

Comment: Hey saurabh, and welcome to [workplace.se]! Have you spoken to your team leader about this? What did he say? Other than not liking him, what is the problem? What do you want to accomplish in this situation? As it is now, there is no way to answer your question, so if you could [edit] it we would be able to give better answers. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Size of your organization, nature of your work, is it paid training etc are few facts which if you put in your question then we can answer it

Comment: I took a stab at re-writing your question, saurabh. If you like it, please take it as a starting point to give some more details on your situation and narrow the question down.

Comment: The purpose of a job isn't to teach you something its to do something that needs to be done for somebody else. You learning how to do that job can either be on them if they want it done right from day 1 or left to you to figure out. Do you not know what needs to be done daily?  I find it hard to believe that after 2.5 months you don't know what you should be doing daily.

Comment: @Ramhound - That may be the purpose of the job from the employer's perspective, but if they want to hire and retain intelligent people, it's best to make sure employees have some level of job satisfaction. Technical growth/learning is extremely important in many professions.

Comment: @JeffO - I don't disagree. I just took issue to the author's complaint he hasn't learned anything.  2.5 months isn't exactly a large window of time to do training.

Comment: @Ramhound - Good point. It is probably not enough time to be writing production code either.

Comment: I'm shocked how many people blame the OP for such a common issue in so many organizations. The lack of true leaders.

Answer (score 3):

> i have complained about him twice so he is angry

There was your first (and second) mistake. Maybe he forgot to assign you work or is waiting for you to learn on your. Is it possible other team members were suppose to be working with you? You're eager to learn and made a mistake. Don't let your emotions get in the way.

Whatever is going on, ask for a meeting. Let your boss know you are ready to take on tasks and ask when he thinks he can assign one to you. There is no reason to "complain" about the situation. Make sure you understand why your boss is doing things this way. If he doesn't have time to meet, that may be another problem. He may not be in a position to drop all of his other duties just to deal with your problems.

Another option is to ask a team member if you can work with them on one of their tasks. Unfortunately, they may want to dump some boring and tedious task on you. Hopefully, they'll share in something to help stretch your skill set.

You are given a completely clean slate to learn whatever you want. Use the tutorials, materials and whatever else you can find on the Internet (Stackoverflow?). If all of your time is wasted, it's your fault. Take control of your learning. And yes, it would be nice if your boss gave you something to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you're in business for yourself, and research the market your business operates in.  Become familiar with the needs of your customer or customers, how the business meets those needs, how the business model is evolving, and what 'should' be in the product development cycle.  If people won't answer direct questions, simply keep your ears perked up.  If you're supposed to be writing software, get on Stack Overflow and look for questions that relate to the platform you should be writing things in.  Study up on those issues - language features, programming methodologies, etc., and practice developing solutions.

It's also a good idea to keep working on writing and language skills.

I worked with someone with database development responsibilities who had grown up in the Middle East and had been left high and dry in the US due to political upheaval in his homeland. He had been a database programmer for several years, but was unsatisfied with his employment situation - to put it mildly. After we had known each other for a year, he asked me to look over his resume - it ran 2 1/2 pages long and did not contain a single properly constructed sentence.  We spent a lunchtime rewriting it, he had a better job offer two days later.  I don't know how long he kept that job - I fell out of contact with him.  I suspect, however, that his communication skills left him with unnecessarily limited prospects.

Anyone in that situation needs to be reading and writing constantly. It's not good enough to be able to understand what someone else is saying, one has to be able to explain their own ideas.  This means writing, thinking about what one is going to say, organizing the message, and figuring out whether something needs to be said at all. One of the most common complaints in the US from employers is that the people that have just graduated from four year university degree programs can't present a simple idea in a single page memo. Managers may be reluctant to assign work to someone who has difficulty explaining what they're doing.

Answer (score 0):

You yourself are of the opinion that you need to learn something. Then how would you expect a team lead to assign you tasks ? Would you give your money to a plumber who is learning to fix taps at your dime ?  
 
If I were you, I would talk to the team lead. Sort out hard feelings. Even apologize if you have come across as over stepping boundaries. Ask if there is a genuine reason why he is not assigning you tasks. Explain him my strengths and weaknesses and the approach I would take for any task assigned. I would also explain what steps I plan to take if I am stuck with a given task. Even draw a map on what I think is the right process once I have completed my task (regression testing etc). From my experience, I would get used to the idea of sitting late at work especially since you are a fresher.  
Stop forming opinions about others and start focusing on how *you* can improve. If nothing works and you are still idling time away, start creating POCs around the technologies you use and demo them to your team lead. Make an effort to show you can be a dependable software engineer.

Comment: thats a big NO.